# Ubuntu does not boot due to disk space full

Tags: ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10.  When I boot Ubuntu it does not start and just shows a blank screen.  I tried `cntrl+alt+f1` and using `df -h` I saw that my `/dev/sda7` is completely full.  I can't even remove old kernels due to low space.  I cannot start Ubuntu, please help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ubuntu has started if you are able to do commands, it is just the gui you are missing.  Now you just need to delete things with the `rm` command.

Please be careful, and make sure you understand what you are doing.

Perhaps you can delete some old logs?  In the `/var/log` folder there are lots of logs.

Anything ending in a number such as `.1`, or a number with a `gz` suffix - `.2.gz` is an old log file.  It is fairly safe to delete these.

However, you can use the `du -shx /*` command to see which of the root directories is using the most space.  It is likely to be the `/home/` directory, and your own home directory.  Probably email or dropbox is taking up the most room.

Comment: ok thank you. I will try it out. Can i delete files from /dev/sda7 ?..My Partition is of 41g and all of the 41g is full so i cant even delete the old kernels.

Comment: `rm` doesn't normally need any additional space.  What happens when you try?

Comment: i tried using rm and deleted files from Downloads and some old kernels. Still when i use df -h it shows that my drive is full .

Comment: @user3209750 Depending on the filesystem, it may take a while to show as freed.  If you have deleted enough stuff, say around 100Mb, reboot and it should work.  Then you can set about really tidying up.

Comment: @user3209750: Are you sure you are really deleting files from the filesystem that is full, and not a different one?  `df` will show you which filesystem is mounted where.  Another possibility is that something is filling the disk as quickly as you are deleting files; `du` may be helpful in finding what that is.

Comment: Kernels are usually on a separate `/boot` partition in Ubuntu so cleaning out old ones typically won't free up much if any space on `/`.

Comment: Linux filesystems often reserve part of the disk's space for the superuser's exclusive use.  Until you've deleted enough stuff for this reserved space to be completely empty, "df -h" will still show the disk as being completely full.

Comment: You only have 41 GB?  That's your problem right there.  Windows 7 is in itself [15 to 20 gigabytes](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/system-requirements).  Trollface.jpg  Looks like Ubuntu is [only 5 GB, though](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements).  Damn you, Microsoft.

Answer (score 10):

I would personally try to boot from a live CD and try mounting /dev/sda7 that way. Once you can get it mounted, you should then go through and see what large files you can delete to free up space.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Can you provide more details on how you would do this?